# How to find out if JTextArea is activated?

Tags: java, swing

I want to write a text editor using Java, so I have a question about JTextArea. I want my program to say when text area is activated and some key is pressed. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "activated"? If it's enabled (through `setEnabled(boolean)`), or if it has the focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About catching keys try:
JTextField.addKeyListener()

About Focus:
JTextField.addFocusListener()